# How to find if a user has shared a post on Salesforce chatter

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

Wanted to know if there is are ways in which I could find if a user in Salesforce has shared a chatter post.

I tried to find if this was possible by querying the [FeedItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm?search_text=Feed) and its associated object and also via [ConnectApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm) but didn't find any possible options.

Comment: When you say shared a post - do you mean they posted something on chatter or shared someone else's post?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I mean a chatter feed post shared by another user.